# What happened when all thread of a warp read the same global memory?

Tags: cuda, gpgpu, gpu

I want to know what happened when all threads of a warp read the same 32-bit address of global memory. How many memory requests are there? Is there any serialization. The GPU is Fermi card, the programming environment is CUDA 4.0.

Besides, can anybody explain the concept of bus utilization? What is the difference between caching loading and non-caching loading? I saw the concept in http://theinf2.informatik.uni-jena.de/theinf2_multimedia/Website_downloads/NVIDIA_Fermi_Perf_Jena_2011.pdf.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### All threads in warp accessing same address in global memory

I could answer your questions off the top of my head for AMD GPUs. For Nvidia, googling found the answers quickly enough.

> I want to know what happened when all threads of a warp read the same 32-bit address of global memory. How many memory requests are
>   there? Is there any serialization. The GPU is Fermi card, the
>   programming environment is CUDA 4.0.

http://developer.download.nvidia.com/CUDA/training/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_Webinars_Best_Practises_For_OpenCL_Programming.pdf, dated 2009, says:

> Coalescing:
>
> Global memory latency: 400-600 cycles. The single most important
>   performance  consideration!
>
> Global memory access by threads of a half warp  can be coalesced to
>   one transaction for word of  size 8-bit, 16-bit, 32-bit, 64-bit or two
>   transactions  for 128-bit.
>
> Global memory can be viewed as composing  aligned segments of 16 and
>   32 words.
>
> Coalescing in Compute Capability 1.0  and 1.1:
>
> K-th thread in a half warp must access the k-th  word in a segment;
>   however, not all threads need to  participate
>
> Coalescing in Compute Capability
>   1.2 and 1.3:
>
> Coalescing for any pattern of access that fits into a  segment size

So, it sounds like having all threads of a warp access the same 32-bit address of global memory will work as well as could be hoped for, in anything >= Compute Capability 1.2. But not for 1.0 and 1.1.

Your card is okay.

I must admit that I have not tested this for Nvidia. I have tested it for AMD.

---

### Difference between cache and uncached load

To start off, look at slide 4 of the presentation you refer to, http://theinf2.informatik.uni-jena.de/theinf2_multimedia/Website_downloads/NVIDIA_Fermi_Perf_Jena_2011.pdf.

I.e. the slide titled "Differences between CPU & GPUs" - that says that CPUs have huge caches, and GPUs don't.

A few years ago such a slide might have said that GPUs don't have any caches at all. However, GPUs have begin to add more and more cache, and/or switch more and more local to cache.

I am not sure if you understand what a "cache" is in computer architecture.  It's a big topic, so I will only provide a short answer.

Basically, a cache is like local memory. Both cache and local memory - are closer to the processor or GPU than DRAM, main memory - whether that be the GPU's private DRAM, or the CPU's system memory. DRAM main memory is called by Nvidia Global Memory. Slide 9 illustrates this.

Both cache and local memory are closer to the GPU than DRAM global memory: on slide 9 they are drawn as being inside the same chip as the GPU, whereas the DRAMs are separate chips. This can have several good effects, on latency, throughput, power - and, yes, bus utilization (related to bandwidth).

Latency: global memory is 400-800 cycles away. This means that if you only had one warp in your application, it would only execute one memory operation every 400-800 cycles.  This means that, in order not to slow down, you need many threads/warps producing memory requests that can be run in parallel, i.e. that have high MLP (Memory Level Parallelism). Fortunately graphics usually does this.  The caches are closer, so will have lower latency.  Your slides do not say what it is, but other places say 50-200 cycles, 4-8X faster than global memory. This translates to needing fewer threads&warps to avoid slowing down.

Throughput/Bandwidth: there is typically more bandwidth to local memory and/or cache than to DRAM global memory.  Your slides say 1+ TB/s versus 177 GB/s - i.e. cache and local memory is more than 5X faster. This higher bandwidth could translate to significantly higher framerates.

Power: you save a lot of power going to cache or local memory rather than to DRAM global memory.  This may not matter to a desktop gaming PC, but it matters to a laptop, or to a tablet PC.  Actually, it matters even to a desktop gaming PC, because less opower means it can be (over)clocked faster.

OK, so local and cache memory are similar in the above?  What's the difference?

Basically, it is easier to program cache than it is local memory.  Very good, expert, nionja programmers are needed to manage local memory properly, copying stuff from global memory as needed, and flushing it out. Whereas cache memory is much easier to manage, because you just doing a cached load, and the memory is put in cache automatically, where it will be accessed faster the next time around.

But caches have a downside as well.

First, they actually burn a bit more power than local memory - or they would, if there were actually separate local and global memories.  However, in Fermi, the local memory may be configured as cache, and vice versa.   (For years GPU folks said "we don't need no stinking cache - cache tags and other overhead are jujst wasteful.)

More importantly, caches tend to operate on cache lines - but not all programs do. This leads to the bus utilization issue you mention. If a warp accesses all words in a cache line, great.  But if a warp only accesses 1 word in a cache line, i.e. 1 4 byte word and then skips 124 bytes, then 128 bytes of data are transferred over the bus, but only 4 bytes are used. I.e. >96% of the bus bandwidth  is being wasted. This is the low bus utilization.

Whereas the very next slide shows that a non-caching load, suich as one might use to load data into local memory, would transfer only 32 bytes, so "only" 28 bytes out of 32 are wasted.  In other words, the non-cache loads could be 4X more efficient, 4X faster, than the cached loads.

Then why not use non-cache loads everywhere?  Because they are harder to program - it requirwes expert ninja programmers.  And caches work pretty well much of the time.

So, instead of paying your expert ninja programmers to spend a lot of time optimizing all of the code to use non-cache loads and hand-managed local memory - instead you do the easy stuff using cached loads, and you let the highly paid expert ninja programmers concentrate on the stuff that the cache does not work well for.

Besides: nobody likes admitting it, but oftentimes the cache does better than the expert ninja programmers.

Hope this helps.
Throughput, power, and bus utilization:  in addition to reducing